# MediaSession does not show background on lock screen

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using `MediaSession` on Lollipop to control playback. It appears to work because my Android Wear device allows me to control playback, however the phone lock screen isn't showing the image from `METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI` and the background on Android Wear isn't showing either. I am using my own custom notification (not media style notification). Here is my MediaSession code.

```
if (mediaSession == null) {
            mediaSession = new MediaSession(this, TAG);


            mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCallback());
        }
        mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

        MediaMetadata.Builder metadataBuilder = new MediaMetadata.Builder();
        metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, getMediaTitle());
        if (imageURL != null) {

            metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI, imageURL);
        }

        mediaSession.setMetadata(metadataBuilder.build());
        PlaybackState.Builder stateBuilder = new PlaybackState.Builder();
        stateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE | PlaybackState.ACTION_REWIND | PlaybackState.ACTION_FAST_FORWARD);

        stateBuilder.setState(playStateStatus == Paused ? PlaybackState.STATE_PAUSED : PlaybackState.STATE_PLAYING, PlaybackState.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 1.0f);

        mediaSession.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build());
        mediaSession.setActive(true);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you setting `.setLargeIcon(albumArtBitmap)` on the NotificationBuilder. That is shown as the background on the lockscreen? aside: Also why not use MediaStyle

Comment: Hmm that didn't fix it. I thought the album art was tied to remote client on prelollipop systems so I assumed it was tied to mediasession on lollipop. I haven't had time to move to the new media style notification yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the answer is using `MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART` so I'm not sure what the point of `METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI` is.

metadataBuilder.putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, bitmap);

Comment: When i try this code, album art show stretch android 4.4.2.